# Online/cloud storage options for GIS file-based data

Tags: cloud-gis, large-datasets, data-storage, storage

I am currently looking into online/cloud-based storage solutions in general and also for my GIS data which consists of shapefiles, rasters, file geodatabases, and the like (no relational databases). Here are my requirements:

1. Unlimited storage (need several hundred gigs to start with)
2. Either unlimited file size or can handle files many GBs in size
3. Just need it for one Windows 7 box right now, but Mac support needed as well
4. Less than $100/yr - most are around $60 looks like
5. An Android app would be nice, not to back up the phone, but to access my backed up files from the phone
6. Backs up external hard drives
7. Can seed the backup with a hard drive and then get the restore sent to me on a HDD as well

From what I have looked at so far, it looks like [CrashPlan](http://www.crashplan.com/) might be my best bet, except no mobile apps available. [Mozy](http://www.mozy.com) used to be unlimited, by apparently c[hanged and now is not](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2379278,00.asp?kc=PCRSS03069TX1K0001121&obref=obinsite). [Carbonite](http://www.carbonite.com) looks promising and has mobile apps, but doesn't backup removable hard drives and I can't find anything about if they let you seed your backup with a removable drive. Anyone currently using any of these services? Know of another service that might fit the bill?

One service/provider per answer please so they can be voted on properly. Thanks.

Comment: Is there anything about this question which is specific to spatial data? If not, its probably best to move it to a forum with a larger user base.

Comment: I have spatial data to backup, so I'm wanting to know the experiences/opinions of my peer group with these backup providers. However, I'm not against moving it to another forum if that would be best.

Comment: I tend to agree with scw, bits is bits, maybe here is more appropriate: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/storage

Comment: I'm closing this question since it'll need rephrasing for another site. I've found a few threads on other sites you may find helpful: http://serverfault.com/questions/60944/cheap-cloud-based-backup; http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/7327/unlimited-and-multi-computer-online-storage-solutions-with-automatic-backup; http://superuser.com/questions/23431/windows-home-server-online-backup-solutions. In general, I'd make sure you have good secondary systems in place if they're offering 'unlimited' service as hosting >500GB will cost them more than you're paying in the long run.